# Share Authentication between MVC applications through WIF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity

I have two website i.e. A and B, where A and B both have their user store separately. If user is authenticated user of A, it should be able to access all authorized pages of B and visa versa.

Can someone help me how i can do this using Windows identity foundation.
Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea that from where i should start. Can you please help!

Comment: Have you integrated MVC application with WIF?

Comment: No i haven't can you please give me any tutorial link or any help material because i heard the name of WIF today so I have no clue so far. I have already read many links but unfortunately none of them addresses my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the main article by MSDN which completely describes [What is Windows Identity Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) that says:

> Windows® Identity Foundation (WIF) is a framework for building
>   identity-aware applications. The framework abstracts the WS-Trust and
>   WS-Federation protocols and presents developers with APIs for building
>   security token services and claims-aware applications. Applications
>   can use WIF to process tokens issued from security token services and
>   make identity-based decisions at the web application or web service.

So you should have *the less problems* for authentication across multiple applications.

*A great start point* would be the MSDN one which is [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*To understand How it works* see [this helpful MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2010/04/03/wif-and-mvc-how-it-works.aspx).

*Another example of WIF + MVC* is available in [Federated Identity with Multiple Partners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359105.aspx) where I exhort you to read the first chapters to understand all underlying principles.

**Update**: Around STS
According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748490.aspx):

> A security token service (STS) is the service component that builds,
>   signs, and issues security tokens according to the WS-Trust and
>   WS-Federation protocols. There’s a lot of work that goes into
>   implementing these protocols, but WIF does all of this work for you,
>   making it feasible for someone who isn’t an expert in the protocols to
>   get an STS up and running with very little effort. You can use a cloud
>   STS such as a LiveID STS, a pre-built STS such as Active Directory®
>   Federation Services (AD FS) 2.0, or, if you want to issue custom
>   tokens or provide custom authentication or authorization, you can
>   build your own custom STS using WIF. WIF makes it easy to build your
>   own STS. For more information, see Building an STS.

The following Links can be helpful around STS:

1. [Building an STS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804740.aspx)
2. [How to: Create a Security Token Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733095%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. [Building A Custom Security Token Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347547.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for resources, i already read the article "How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF" but it doesn't mention how i can make STS. it just use a url of STS can you please tell me how to create that STS.

Comment: @AwnAli I updated the answer :) You can meet your purpose just by some searches on the web.